# Terminal Buffer: error in process filter: Invalid face: unspecified

Tags: ansi-term, term, bash, zsh

On Fedora 25 with GNU Emacs 25.1.90 (which I am running via an AppImage, you can download it from [here](https://bintray.com/fusion809/AppImages/GNU_Emacs#files) and test out your theories as to what's wrong if you would like, remember AppImages will only work on Linux though) with a config file [found here](https://github.com/fusion809/emacs/blob/master/.emacs) I get an error whenever I start `ansi-term` or `term` via `M-x ansi-term<RET>` or `M-x term<RET>`, respectively, namely:

```
error in process filter: Invalid face: unspecified
```

I does not seem to matter too much which shell I use as I have tried my default shell, Z Shell (Zsh) and the more popular Bash shell and I get the exact same error message. Despite this the Bourne shell (`/bin/sh`) works fine. The Emacs debugger gives the following backtrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Invalid face" unspecified)
  internal-get-lisp-face-attribute(unspecified :foreground nil)
  face-attribute(unspecified :foreground nil default)
  face-foreground(unspecified nil default)
  term-handle-colors-array(1)
  term-handle-ansi-escape(#<process terminal> 109)
  term-emulate-terminal(#<process terminal> "[1m[7m%[27m[1m[0m                                                                               

")
```

If you're wondering why I don't just use GNU Emacs 25.1 installed via the DNF package manager well using it lead to some issues with Octave syntax-highlighting per [this chat room discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49851/discussion-between-tobias-and-brenton-horne).

It seems to be colouring-related as when I comment out the `PS1=...` line in my `~/.bashrc` file this error goes away and Bash starts without a problem.